# Aborted (core dumped) removing element from vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, berkeley-sockets

I'm trying to learn C++ using "MUD Game Programming" and I am working through the examples, but when I try to erase a connection from a vector I get an error: "Aborted (core dumped)." This usually happens when erasing the last one from the vector. I have tried solutions such as checking to see if the iterator != connlist.end() before deleting, and trying to use connlist.clear() if there is only one element left in the list, but these don't seem to help.

I am using g++ to compile and working on Cygwin.

The error happens at connlist.erase(), which you can see is called when the user types "quit."

```
void NMudServer::StartListening() {

    fd_set read_set;
    std::vector<SocketLib::Connection>::iterator itr;       
    std::vector<SocketLib::Connection>::iterator itr2;  
    TIMEVAL zerotime;
    zerotime.tv_usec = 0;
    zerotime.tv_sec = 0;
    char buffer[buf_len];
    int err;
    lsock.Listen( default_port );

    if( lsock.IsListening() ) {
        std::cout << "Telnet listening on port " << default_port << "." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Could not start Telnet listening socket! - Last error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    while( lsock.IsListening() ) {
        FD_ZERO( &read_set );
        FD_SET( lsock.GetSock(), &read_set );

        for( itr = connlist.begin(); itr != connlist.end(); ++itr ) {
            FD_SET( itr->GetSock(), &read_set );
        }
    
        int sel = select( 0x7FFFFFFF, &read_set, NULL, NULL, &zerotime );           

        if( sel > 0 ) {

            if( FD_ISSET( lsock.GetSock(), &read_set ) ) {
                SocketLib::DataSocket dsock = lsock.Accept();
                SocketLib::Connection conn( dsock, buf_len );           
                connlist.push_back( conn );
                conn.Send( "Hello!\r\n", 8 );
            }           

            for( itr = connlist.begin(); itr != connlist.end(); ++itr ) {

                if( FD_ISSET( itr->GetSock(), &read_set ) ) {

                    err = itr->Receive();

                    if( err == -1 ) {
                        std::cout << "Socket receiving error!" << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Exiting due to error." << std::endl;
                        CloseAllConnections(); // This is when the connection is closed. Need to only close the one connection.
                        break;
                    } else if( err == 0 ) {
                        itr->Close();
                        connlist.erase( itr );
                        --itr;
                    } else if( itr->IsReady() ) {
                        int size;
                        size = itr->GetData( buffer );

                        if( strcmp( buffer, "servquit\r\n" ) == 0 ) {
                            CloseAllConnections();
                        } else if( strcmp( buffer, "quit\r\n" ) == 0 ) {
                            itr->Close();
                            connlist.erase( itr ); // When you go to erase the last element, it errors
                            --itr;
                        } else {
                            // Echo back the data to all connections
                            for( itr2 = connlist.begin(); itr2 != connlist.end(); ++itr2 ) {                                        

                                if( itr2->GetSock() != itr->GetSock() ) {

                                    int err2;
                                    itr2->Send( buffer, size );

                                    if( err2 == -1 ) {
                                        std::cout << "Socket sending error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    itr2->Send( "\r\n", 2 );
                                }

                            } // end for
                        }// end if-else

                        itr->Reset();

                    } // end if-else-else

                } // end if
            } // end for
        } // end if sel
    } // end while
}

void NMudServer::CloseAllConnections() {
    lsock.Close();

    std::vector<SocketLib::Connection>::iterator itr;
    for( itr = connlist.begin(); itr != connlist.end(); ++itr ) {
        itr->Close();
    }

    WSACleanup();
}
```

For reference, the book is:
Penton, Ron. *MUD Game Programming.* Boston, MA, USA: Course Technology / Cengage Learning, 2003.

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating a vector and erasing elements from it inside the loop. That's never a good idea. `vector::erase` invalidates the iterator you then use to iterate further.

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

Reason for this is that a vector might <strike>reallocate</strike> and/or move elements when you erase an element.

### Possible solution:

Just close those connections inside that loop and perform an erase-remove afterwards:

```
connlist.erase(std::remove_if(connlist.begin(), connlist.end(), is_closed), connlist.end());
```

with `is_closed` being something like:

```
is_closed = [](const SocketLib::Connection& c) {return !c.open();};
```

PS: I don't know that `SocketLib` so you might change that `is_closed` a bit

PPS: use range-based for loops like `for(auto& connection : connlist) {...}`

### Edit:

As mentioned in a comment, the vector will not reallocate in this case, the other points still stand.

Comment: I don't think vector can reallocate: 
Iterator validity: "... pointers and references to elements before position (or first) are guaranteed to keep referring to the same elements they were referring to before the call." (quote is from the link you refer to)

Comment: @luantkow citing from linked article `[erase] invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator` so the loop isn't valid anymore. Though it won't reallocate as you said

Comment: it may be possible to use `std::erase` before to move sockets to be closed to the end, then close them, then delete them

Comment: also change from `connlist.erase( itr );` to `itr = connlist.erase( itr );` would solve the problem with usage of invalidated iterator, wouldn't it?

Comment: @luantkow yes and that would also be less effort I guess but that causes more moving inside the vector. The erase-remove idiom is cleaner IMO.

Comment: I was able to implement the above solution and it looks like it got me pat the vector issue,  thanks!!

Comment: @noworld if this answer is the accepted solution, remember to mark it accordingly